# Callback for backbone child view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have been all over google looking for this, I can't come up with a clear solution.

I have a chatView that renders a collectionView of messages (messagesView). I need to wait until all the messages are fetched and rendered before I can run a function to scroll to the bottom of the list of messages.

Here is a stripped up version of my code.

```
var socket             = io.connect(),   
    Marionette         = require('backbone.marionette'),
    MessagesCollection = require('../collections/messages'),
    MessagesView       = require('./messages'),
    MessageModel       = require('../models/message');

module.exports = ChatView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({ 

    className: 'chat col-sm-9',
    template: require('../../templates/chat.hbs'),
    events: {
        'focusin input.message': 'userTyping',
        'focusout input.message': 'userNotTyping',
        'submit #chat-form': 'sendMessage'
    },                    

    initialize: function() {

        var self = this;

        /* Make an instance of the collection for the specific chat */
        window.messages = new MessagesCollection([], { chat_id: this.options.chatRoom });
        messages.fetch({
            success: function(models) {
                App.data.messages = messages;
                _.delay(function() {
                  self.scrollChat();
                }, 1000);
            } 
        });

        // The view for a collection of messages
        window.messagesView = new MessagesView({ collection: messages });

        /* Create an instance of a specific room for client to admin chat */
        socket.emit('createRoom', this.options.chatRoom);

        /* Resize the chat when the window changes */
        $(window).on("resize", this.scrollChat);

    },         

    onRender: function() {

        /* Render all the messages inside the chatbox */
        var $chatbox = this.$el.find('.message-content'); 
        $chatbox.append(messagesView.render().$el);

        window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Chat View: chat view was rendered!');

    },


    scrollChat: function() {

        var $headerNav   = $('.navbar').outerHeight();
        var $typeMessage = $('.type-message').outerHeight();
        var $extraHeight = $headerNav + $typeMessage;

        $('.chat').height($(window).height() - $headerNav);
        $('.message-content').height($(window).height() - $extraHeight);

        var pane = $('.message-content'); 
        pane.jScrollPane({
            autoReinitialise: true
        });
        window.paneApi = pane.data('jsp');
        paneApi.scrollTo(0, $('.collection').height());

        if($(window).width() < 768) {
            paneApi.destroy();
            $('.message-content').scrollTop(500);
        } else {
            paneApi.reinitialise();
        }

    }

});
```

Maybe I should move some parts around, but I need to fetch a specific list of messages that is defined by `this.options.chatRoom`, so therefore I need to fetch those messages within the above view.

The issue is I have to set a `_.delay` within the fetch method to simulate the rendering of the messages, we know in the `success` callback the messages have been retrieved but the view hasn't been rendered, meaning the `scrollChat` function can't calculate properly.

I am asking how should I wait until the whole list has been rendered to the DOM and then execute.

The best I could find was using a marionette region and then using `onShow` but I would have to re factor some code and rather ask this first.

Hope I was clear, this is more of an annoyance and would like to scroll the chat properly.

Comment: You could try adding the scrollChat() function into the MessagesView onShow function. Then only create the messages view once the data has been retrieved. Otherwise you can even just add backbone.wreqr and send a message from the messagesView to this view that then calls the scrollChat

Comment: Thanks for the input, I don't think `onShow` gets triggered as it is not a region, I tried... When you say send a message you mean `trigger` or literally send a message with my `sendMessage` function. If the latter I don't see how I can create a message within the message view as it does not contain my input element.

Comment: Which version of Marionette do you use?

Comment: Honestly, I am not quite sure how to check that, I haven't updated it in awhile. Why are there new features, I can easily update it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah, collectionViews don't have onShow methods.

Trigger exactly. But collectionViews should have an onRender function that gets called after the children load.

Try adding this line here

```
this.listenTo(window.messagesView, "collection:rendered", self.scrollChat);
```

Comment: Yeah good try, I tried something similar to that earlier, unfortunately it's not being triggered. I even tried using sub-pub and triggering an event within the collectionView. It seems the only thing that works is sub-pub within the itemView, but it gets called for each message lol.

Comment: I might have to settle for _.delay for now and move on, and as time progresses I may figure something out. I am still open to ideas :)